# Issue on including SwipedTabs on ActionBar in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I want to include only SwipedTabs on screen. So I make code without TabListeners like this,

`

```
package com.example.swipetabexample;

 import android.app.ActionBar;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    ActionBar ab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ab = getActionBar();
        ActionBar.Tab at= ab.newTab();
        at.setText("Tab1");
        ab.addTab(at);

    }
}


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`
```

When I run this code I found always error.But I checked again and again but I can't find what's wrong. I found many blogs they had also implemented Swiped Tabs like this but with fragment with TabListener.
But First of all,I want to see only the Tabs on screen.
Here I give the error shown in Logcat

```
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233): Process: com.example.swipetabexample, PID: 1233
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.swipetabexample/com.example.swipetabexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.configureTab(ActionBarImpl.java:478)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:504)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:492)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at com.example.swipetabexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-20 14:52:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1233):     ... 11 more
01-20 16:59:43.564: D/dalvikvm(1368): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 5% free 3415K/3568K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
01-20 16:59:43.572: D/dalvikvm(1368): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3633K/3792K, paused 2ms, total 5ms
01-20 16:59:43.592: I/dalvikvm-heap(1368): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.039MB for 2536932-byte allocation
01-20 16:59:43.600: D/dalvikvm(1368): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6111K/6272K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
01-20 16:59:43.664: D/AndroidRuntime(1368): Shutting down VM
01-20 16:59:43.668: W/dalvikvm(1368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ce3b20)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Process: com.example.swipetabexample, PID: 1368
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.swipetabexample/com.example.swipetabexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.configureTab(ActionBarImpl.java:478)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:504)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:492)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at com.example.swipetabexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-20 16:59:43.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     ... 11 more

Comment: what error exactly you are getting ?

Comment: Yes, while run the program on emulator it says, "Unfortunately,SwipeTabexample stopped working" and the other errors which are shown in the Logcat is in above post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the same one through Eclipse Bydefault code generator. By selecting option TabActivity instead of choosing BlankActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in on create

```
 getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // show the given tab
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // hide the given tab
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // probably ignore this event
    }
};




 ab = getActionBar();
    ActionBar.Tab at= ab.newTab();
    at.setText("Tab1");
    ab.addTab(at).setTabListener(tabListener);
```

Comment: I got runtime exception And the error I getting which I saw in the LogCat and that I post in my question.